# Ideals in a Noetherian ring

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring, let $\mathfrak{i}$ be an ideal of $R$, let $\{x_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}}$ be a set of generators for $\mathfrak{i}$, suppose $\mathcal{A}$ has infinitely many elements.

Now, assume $R$ Noetherian. Can I extract from $\{x_{\alpha}\}$ a finite set of generators for $\mathfrak{i}$?

I know since $R$ is Noetherian there are finitely many generators for $\mathfrak{i}$. But can I find this set extracting finitely many elements from a set of generators arbitrarily fixed at the beginning?

Comment: Yes. Choose any $x_{\alpha_1}$ at random. If this does not generate $\mathfrak{i}$, there is some other $x_{\alpha_2}$ which does not lie in the ideal generated by $x_{\alpha_1}$. If the ideal generated by these two is not all of $\mathfrak{i}$, we can find a third $x_{\alpha_3}$ which does not lie in there, et cetera. Eventually this process must terminate by the ascending chain condition.

Comment: Another way to think about this (which is equivalent) is that $\mathfrak{i}$ must be finitely generated, say by $r_1,\ldots,r_n$. Each $r_i$ can be written as an $R$-linear combination of finitely many of the $x_\alpha$'s, and if you take $S$ to be the (finite!) set of $x_\alpha$'s which are used in writing the $r_i$'s this way, then those $x_\alpha$'s constitute a finite generating set for $\mathfrak{i}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Start with one element among the set $\{x_\alpha\}$, call it $y_0$. If $\left<y_0\right> = \mathfrak i$ then you are done. Otherwise, there is a $y_1 \in \mathfrak \{x_\alpha\}$ such that $y_1 \notin \left<y_0\right>$. If $\left<y_0, y_1\right> = \mathfrak i$ then you are done. Otherwise, there is a $y_2$...

If this process never terminates, then you get a strictly increasing chain of ideals, which is impossible. Therefore at some point you have obtained a complete generating set.